# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element

Tags: json, bash, shell, jenkins-pipeline

I have some issues while a Syntax JSON. I want to write all parameters of jenkins job pipeline build with parameters into a JSON file using ${params}! In my case i have 4 parameters(apis:multi-select,name:string,version:single-select and status:Boolean), there is the script Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {              
            steps {              
                script{
                  sh "./test.sh ${params}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Content of test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(echo -n $@ | tr -d ']['| jq -nRs 'inputs |split(",")'| sed 's/:/":"/')
echo $a > file.json
```

The output in jenkins

```
+ ./test.sh [apis:dev,qa,prod, name:element, version:g3, status:true]
[ "apis":"dev", "qa", "prod", " name":"element", " version":"g3", " status":"true" ]
```

Result in file.json

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data
```

My question is how format the output to obtain a clean result in file.json like this

```
[{
    "apis": ["dev",
        "qa",
        "prod"
    ],
    " name": "element",
    " version": "g3",
    " status": "true"
}]
```

PS: I can't use Groovy

Comment: `"apis":"dev"` is not valid syntax inside an array literal (neither in JSON nor JavaScript). It would be valid inside an object literal (`{...}`), but  `apis":"dev", "qa", "prod"` is not valid in an object literal.

Comment: yes i know , i don't know how to be an object in my case ! you have any idea how ?

Comment: As Felix told you, use curly braces to define an object.

Comment: BTW, `echo -n $@` is a really bad idea in general. See [BashPitfalls #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), output from https://shellcheck.net/, and the excellent answer by Stephane on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: Frankly -- how are those params getting *into* Jenkins? I'd hope we could get them back out in a better format instead of taking a format that's meant for humans to read during debugging but utterly unsuited to machine consumption.

Comment: It's a build with parameters in jenkins, so as i sayed i have 4 parameters`(apis:multi-select,name:string,version:single-select and status:Boolean)` and i still have a problem with syntax JSON.using params. ${params} give me this result `[apis:dev,qa,prod, name:element, version:g3, status:true]` I need a clean format!

Comment: if you have an idea better then this please tell me Charles. My objective is to save all the parameters $params in JSON file with shell!

Comment: That's a Jenkins question, not a bash question. Need to ask it with the right tagging to get it in front of the right people.